# Immutable view inside zoomable scrollview [react-native]

Tags: react-native

i'd like to know if it's possible to put a View inside a zoomable ScrollView but when the user zooms the scrollview, the view's size wont change. The view must be inside the scrollview because the image on the scrollview is bigger than the screen and i`ll render the view overlaying the image in a precise x:y position. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

kinda extreme go horse but if you put the prop onScroll inside scrolView you can get the zoom and divide the width/height of the view by the zoomScale

onScroll={(event) => this.setState({ zoomScale:event.nativeEvent.zoomScale})}